# Global variable seg fault

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault and I cannot figure out why. I have a global TcpClient object that has a pointer to an Agent object. I am trying to access the agent pointer in a function when the segmentation fault occurs. In main, I have the cout statements before and after I set the agent member in TcpClient and both statements give me the same address.

```
TcpClient client((char*)PORT);
Agent* agent = new Agent;

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    //initialization code for agent's members
    cout<<"\nagent: "<<agent;
    client.setAgent(agent); //set it here
    cout<<"\nclient agent: "<<client.getAgent()<<"\n";
}
```

Then I have this function in TcpClient that gets called during the run (after setting the agent of course). I get the segmentation fault when I try to access agent. I have a cout statement in the beginning that tells me agent is 0x0.

```
void TcpClient::getCommand(char* command) { 
    std::cout<<"\nagent: "<<agent;

}
```

The setAgent is a typical setter -

```
void TcpClient::setAgent(Agent*& a) {agent = a;}



class Agent;
class TcpClient {
    //functions and stuff
private:
    Agent* agent;
};
```

The agent member isn't accessed anywhere else in the code. The only thing I can come up with is that there is something about the TcpClient object being global that could make this happen, but I do not know what. Am I right about this? Any help is appreciated.

When I run the code, the debugger says -

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memcpy_ssse3_rep () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-rep.S:1454
1454    ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-rep.S: No such file or directory.
    in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-rep.S
(gdb) back
#0  __memcpy_ssse3_rep ()
    at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-rep.S:1454
#1  0x08049c52 in Agent::setGoal (this=0x0, g=...) at agent.cpp:33
#2  0x0805075e in TcpClient::getCommand (this=0x805aac8, 
command=0xbffff18d "1 3 1\n") at tcpclient.cpp:80
#3  0x08050b8d in TcpClient::communicate (this=0x805aac8) at tcpclient.cpp:153
#4  0x0804e0f8 in main (argc=1, args=0xbffff3f4) at mainclient.cpp:119
```

Comment: Don't use `new` when you don't need it. Don't use global variables. Don't use `char*`. Use a debugger to see where the segfault occurs.

Comment: Where/when is `Agent* agent = new Agent;` being called?

Comment: That is in the main file above the int main() function.

Comment: I do that because I need to access that in a thread function in main.

Comment: What did your debugger say? Seems to me like you are running into static initialisation order problems, and that the code pasted does not accurately represent the code you're _actually_ running.

Comment: original post is updated with debugger

Comment: If that's the case, leave myAgent as a pointer (`Agent*`) and simply do `myagent = a;`

Comment: (Thought I posted this earlier but I guess it didn't finalize or something) - I do not have enough rep to answer my own question. I got the segmentation fault to go away, but I'm not sure why. I have a function called communicate (which just lets server and client talk to each other) that calls the getCommand function I posted above. Right before I call getCommand, there was a memset call for a local char*. All I did was remove that line and the segmentation fault went away. I don't know why that worked, but it did. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a function called communicate (which just lets server and client talk to each other) that calls the getCommand function I posted above. Right before I call getCommand, there was a memset call for a local char*. All I did was remove that line and the segmentation fault went away.

Thanks for help everyone.

Comment: originally was a comment because I did not have enough rep to answer, but figured I would go ahead make it an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the compiler/linker warnings, I'm fairly sure it'll be throwing some at you about ambiguous names.

Do not use "agent" as a variable name for class members when you've already defined it earlier as a global; use something like `private: Agent* myAgent;` (and of course change setAgent to use it) and you should hopefully find the issue goes away.

Additionally, *& basically cancels itself out; the private member is a pointer so you should be using a pointer in the set method - I suspect your segfault is because of a bad operation on either what it thinks is a pointer and actually isn't or vice versa.

Comment: I don't get any warnings when I compile it. Unfortunately, this did not help the problem I have now, but I will remember this in future programs.

Comment: also, why are you using `TcpClient::setAgent(Agent*& a)` - the private member is a pointer so it should just be `Agent* a` - please also show the code for `TcpClient::getAgent()`

Comment: Agent*& TcpClient::getAgent() {return myAgent;}

Comment: yeah, declare myAgent as simply `Agent` not `Agent*&` then in setAgent do `myAgent = *a;`

Comment: What if he doesn't want a copy, but for the two pointers to point to the same object?  In that case, what's being done is completely reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Is `void TcpClient::setAgent(Agent*& a) {agent = a;}` written as intended, or did you mean `Agent *a`?

If you pass an `Agent` object, the syntax is `Agent &a`, which means "`a` is the address of the passed `Agent` object."

If you pass a pointer (which you're doing here), the syntax is `Agent *a`, which means "`a` is passed as a (possibly null) pointer to an `Agent` object."

Comment: Well no, Agent *a would be passing the address of an Agent object, because that is what pointer contains.  Agent &a would be passing an actual Agent variable to the TcpClient, and if you wanted the TcpClient Agent to point to the same object, you'd still need to get the memory location by calling `agent = &a;`.

Comment: I meant it as is. My understanding is that I am passing a reference to a pointer, instead of just a copy. So when I access the pointer and change something about it, it gets changed in other places as well.

Comment: What the OP is doing is passing a reference to a pointer, so that he has a handle on the actual pointer variable he passed in.  If he wanted, he could change what a points to and it would also change what the global agent variable points to, but that is not what is being done so it seems unnecessary.  `setAgent(Agent *a)` should suffice.